# ¿Cómo modelar datos en Firebase para app tipo tinder?

Tags: base-de-datos, firebase, nosql, realtime-database

llevo días intentando crear una funcionalidad en mi app para añadir una funcionalidad tipo Tinder/favoritos. Creo que el problema que tengo es no saber modelar los datos en Firebase. A continuación expongo la necesidad que tengo y lo que he intentado.

Os agradecería que si la pregunta no se entiende o no la veis acorde a las normas, me lo comuniquéis e intento mejorarla. Gracias.

**Requerimiento y configuración actual**

Los usuarios deben poder marcar animales como favoritos a través de una especie de juego, tipo tinder. Le debo mostrar a los usuarios animales de un tipo en concreto (gatos o perros), si el usuario lo marca como favorito, dicho animal no debe volver a aparecer en el "juego" y si le hace "swipe" (no lo marca como no favorito), tampoco debe volver a aparecerle en el juego.

Tengo tres colecciones principales envueltas en esta *feature*: `Usuarios`, `favourites` y `animals`.

Los documentos de `favourites`, tienen el id de un usuario y un array de ids con los ids de los animales a los que el usuario le ha dado like.

He probado actualmente con este código:

```dart
 Future<List<Animal>> fetchNoFavouriteAnimals({
    required int limit,
    required AnimalFilter filter,
    required String userId,
    String? lastId,
  }) async {
    final favouriteAnimalsOfUser =
        (await _store.collection(_favouriteColl).doc(userId).get())
            .data()!['shelter-animals'] as List;

    var query = _store
        .collection(_shelterAnimalColl)
        .where(Animal.adoptedKey, isEqualTo: false)
        .where(Animal.hiddenKey, isEqualTo: false)
        .where(Animal.animalTypeKey, isEqualTo: filter.animalType)
        .where(FieldPath.documentId, whereNotIn: favouriteAnimalsOfUser)
        .orderBy(Animal.animalIdKey);

    if (lastId != null) {
      query = query.startAfter([lastId]);
    }

    final docs = await query.limit(limit).get();
    return docs.docs.map((e) {
      return Animal.fromJson(e.data(), e.id);
    }).toList();
  }
```

La idea es poder hacer una consulta que también pagine los datos, de ahí los parámetros `lastId`. `AnimalFilter`, solo se está utilizando para determinar si cojo perros o gatos.

**Problema**

Creo que el mayor problema que estoy teniendo es poder modelar los datos y las relaciones de una forma correcta, para poder pasar a través de las limitaciones de Firebase. En este caso, la **limitación** que no me deja continuar es que la consulta `.where(FieldPath.documentId, whereNotIn: favouriteAnimalsOfUser)`, no permite que `favouriteAnimalsOfUser`, un array, tenga más de 10 elementos. Por tanto, cuando el usuario está jugando y marca su décimo animal, todo deja de funcionar.

Os agradecería mucho si me podéis indicar/guiar para modelar los datos de una forma más óptima, que me permita evitar este inconveniente que estoy teniendo con Firebase.

Answer (score 0):

No he conseguido resolver el problema modificando la estructura de la base de datos, pero sí he podido encontrar una solución alternativa que comparto y explico por si a alguien le hiciera falta en algún momento realizar algo parecido.

```dart
  Future<List<Animal>> fetchNoFavouriteAnimals({
    required int limit,
    required AnimalFilter filter,
    required String userId,
    String? lastId,
  }) async {
    final favouriteAnimalsOfUser =
        (await _store.collection(_favouriteColl).doc(userId).get())
            .data()!['shelter-animals'] as List;

    var query = _store
        .collection(_shelterAnimalColl)
        .where(Animal.adoptedKey, isEqualTo: false)
        .where(Animal.hiddenKey, isEqualTo: false)
        .where(Animal.animalTypeKey, isEqualTo: filter.animalType)
        .orderBy(Animal.animalIdKey);

    if (lastId != null) {
      query = query.startAfter([lastId]);
    }

    final snapshot = await query.limit(limit).get();
    // If docs length is less than limit, then filter and return animals.
    if (snapshot.docs.length < limit) {
      return snapshot.docs.where((doc) {
        return !favouriteAnimalsOfUser.contains(doc.id);
      }).map((e) {
        return Animal.fromJson(e.data(), e.id);
      }).toList();
    }

    // If docs length is equal to limit, then filter and choose
    // what to do after.
    final docs = snapshot.docs.where((doc) {
      return !favouriteAnimalsOfUser.contains(doc.id);
    });

    if (docs.length < limit) {
      final necessaryElements = limit - docs.length;
      final lastId = snapshot.docs.last.id;
      final extraAnimals = await fetchNoFavouriteAnimals(
        limit: necessaryElements,
        filter: filter,
        userId: userId,
        lastId: lastId,
      );
      final animals = docs.map((e) => Animal.fromJson(e.data(), e.id)).toList();
      return [...animals, ...extraAnimals];
    } else {
      return docs.map((e) => Animal.fromJson(e.data(), e.id)).toList();
    }
  }
```

La solución a la que llegué es crear una Función recursiva que se llame a sí misma para obtener un número determinado de documentos de Firebase (`limit`).

La funcionalidad que se quiere alcanzar es poder descargar de forma paginada los documentos en una colección de Firebase, para lo cual, entre otros filtros (`AnimalFilter filter`), necesitamos obtener los animales que ya se han marcado como favoritos, para no volver a mostrarlos en la app.

```dart
final favouriteAnimalsOfUser =
        (await _store.collection(_favouriteColl).doc(userId).get())
            .data()!['shelter-animals'] as List;
```

Lo idóneo sería usar dicha lista en la consulta, en un `where`, `.where(FieldPath.documentId, whereNotIn: favouriteAnimalsOfUser)`, pero Firebase tiene la limitación de que la lista pasada a `whereNotIn` no puede tener más de 10 elementos.

Así que la única solución que encontré fue descargar los elementos de la colección ordenándolos por Id, de forma que si descargo `limit` elementos y de dichos elementos, alguno se encuentra ya marcado como favorito `favouriteAnimalsOfUser`, descargo `n` elementos más; donde n es `limit` - `elementos repetidos`.

Aquí creo la consulta base, con los filtros necesarios.

```dart
 var query = _store
        .collection(_shelterAnimalColl)
        .where(Animal.adoptedKey, isEqualTo: false)
        .where(Animal.hiddenKey, isEqualTo: false)
        .where(Animal.animalTypeKey, isEqualTo: filter.animalType)
        .orderBy(Animal.animalIdKey);
```

Aquí pagino los datos para coger los `n` elementos siguientes al id del último elemento previamente cogido, y obtengo los documentos de la base de datos.

```dart
if (lastId != null) {
    query = query.startAfter([lastId]);
}

final snapshot = await query.limit(limit).get();
```

Aquí compruebo si el número de elementos descargados, es menor que `limit`, en caso de serlo, quiere decir que no hay más elementos en la base de datos para poder descargar, por lo tanto, filtro los elementos repetidos y retorno los no repetidos.

```dart
if (snapshot.docs.length < limit) {
      return snapshot.docs.where((doc) {
        return !favouriteAnimalsOfUser.contains(doc.id);
      }).map((e) {
        return Animal.fromJson(e.data(), e.id);
      }).toList();
}
```

Si la cantidad de elementos descargados es igual al límite indicado, se filtran los elementos repetidos. Si hay documentos repetidos se vuelve a invocar a la función `fetchNoFavouriteAnimals` recursivamente, para obtener los animales restantes hasta alcanzar `limit` o el final de la base de datos.

Si no hay animales repetidos, se retornan los datos y no se hacen más búsquedas.

```dart
  final docs = snapshot.docs.where((doc) {
      return !favouriteAnimalsOfUser.contains(doc.id);
    });

    if (docs.length < limit) {
      final necessaryElements = limit - docs.length;
      final lastId = snapshot.docs.last.id;
      final extraAnimals = await fetchNoFavouriteAnimals(
        limit: necessaryElements,
        filter: filter,
        userId: userId,
        lastId: lastId,
      );
      final animals = docs.map((e) => Animal.fromJson(e.data(), e.id)).toList();
      return [...animals, ...extraAnimals];
    } else {
      return docs.map((e) => Animal.fromJson(e.data(), e.id)).toList();
    }
```